# Place buttons at center of screen

Tags: android, android-layout

This is my layout. I want these button should come at a center of screen either its is mobile or tablet. How can i achieve this. Please help me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/scrollView" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@color/ubc_grey">
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/titleTextView" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="@color/slate_grey"  android:text="@string/title_home_map_view" android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center" android:textSize="20dp"/>

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_centerInParent="true" android:layout_below="@+id/titleTextView" 
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:gravity="center"  android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

            <Button android:id="@+id/category" android:layout_width="250dp" android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:text="@string/choose_category" android:textColor="@color/white" android:textSize="18dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>

            <Button android:id="@+id/range" android:layout_width="250dp" android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:text="@string/select_range" android:textColor="@color/white" android:layout_marginTop="20dp" 
                android:textSize="18dp" android:layout_gravity="center"/>

            <Button android:id="@+id/useMyCurrentLocation" android:layout_width="250dp" android:layout_height="60dp"
                 android:layout_marginTop="20dp" android:textColor="@color/white" android:text="@string/button_use_my_current_location" 
                 android:layout_gravity="center" android:textSize="18dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

This is what I'm trying to achieve

[image]

Comment: why do you have a scroll layout if you want the items at the center of the screen ?

Comment: In case of small screen these button will not visible if i remove scrollview from here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this xml code. Here i have removed your color and the String Part.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/category"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:text="choose_category"
            android:textSize="18dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/range"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="select_range"
            android:textSize="18dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/useMyCurrentLocation"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="button_use_my_current_location"
            android:textSize="18dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Also you can see the Screen shot attached below:

[image]

Hope you got the point.

feel free to comment.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

you have 4th line of

```
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" lay>
```

You might need to remove the lay at the end of it :)

Cheers

Comment: I did check your post, "This is what I'm trying to achieve" image is what I come out with, except the colors and strings are not defined. If am missing out something, then you being unclear

Answer (score 0):

xml for you:

```
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/ubc_grey">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:background="@color/slate_grey"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/title_home_map_view"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="20dp" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/category"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:text="@string/choose_category"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18dp" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/range"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="@string/select_range"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18dp" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/useMyCurrentLocation"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="@string/button_use_my_current_location"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```